# How to measure the PCB size?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, pcb-fabrication

Can somebody share me your methods measuring the PCB size in CAM Software ?

In PCB house ,we always measure the size according to the centre of outline and get the final size of the unit board or panel. but that can't be matched with the size in panel drawing given by customers. if we deduce the outline width ,then we can get the same data.

Take a project for example, In the panel drawing, the unit size is 79.3*98.4 mm,when we measure the size in Gerber by our way , the final size is 79.42*98.52 mm, the outline width is just 0.12 mm

See the picture below to get clear issues.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

How do you define the final size from the engineer view ? Shall we all follow the size in the panel drawing ?

Comment: I've always drawn my PCBs assuming that the edge of the board is the center of the line around the edge of the board. So the width of the line is irrelevant. Don't know if that's just me, but all of my PCBs have arrived from various manufacturers and been the correct size (except for one who ignored my mechanical outline and used the keepout instead ...)

Comment: Hi brhans,that is just the way we measure the board size, Widt of the line won't be relevant to the final size. But the customer sending our files above assume the inner side of line as the edge of board ,if we can know it ahead, it is not problem ,we can use their way and make modification accordingly in our production files to match the size as required, The customer replied me finally that the data in panel drawing is always valid, We had got it and fixed the issues up .Thanks for your input.

Comment: Additonal comments on your input : Mechanical outline will be the priority files the fab house will use to make board size, Keepout layer ( Keep the circuits out) is just the files for reference ,in generally ,they have the same size and will be included together in zip Gerber files,but when there is only Keepout layer, Fab house should ask for your approval if they can use "Keepout layer" to make the board or ask a new Mechanical outline. Anyway, Details-oriented and good communcation will make the sucessful boards finally. They need involvements from both of us ( PCB designer and Fab house )

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the customer has given you a route tool path instead of an outline track.

If you can use the inner edge of their tracks to define the outline you should meet their needs. Or they can probably change their tool settings to produce an outline whose center line defines the board shape, but without knowing what tool they use we can hardly say how to do that.

Comment: @ The photon,Thanks for your input,I will advise the customer make a change on the tool settings to produce an outline with center line defines the board shape, It seems the best and common way accepted in the industry ,Right ?

Comment: I've seen it done both ways. But when providing a route tool path I'd rather use a line thickness that's realistic as a route tool diameter .